# Capture whole android screen from service without root

Tags: android, screenshot

I need to capture whole android screen from service code and save bitmap to sd card.
I dont have root, so cant use framebuffer. And I cant depend on debug server.

There is ASL http://code.google.com/p/android-screenshot-library/, but is there a way to do that without installing some native service, only from my code?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?  Why would you want to capture the screen from a service?

Comment: I need to send screenshots via TCP to PC on desktop widget button click.

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately, this is not possible, for obvious privacy and security reasons.

Comment: @Rakesh: Via a mechanism not readily available to SDK developers. That's what the ASL library the OP links to does, is offer a script-kiddie way of using that feature, but it requires access to a machine running the Android SDK (at least once per boot, and possibly more frequently than that).

Answer (score -1):

you could get your app to have a transparent view so.when a screenshot is about to be taken the app opens the view then screenshots the view